# Angularjs Select option binding

Tags: html, angularjs, select, frontend

I have a weird problem where I can bind to the option change on the view but when I console log the value of the changed variable it's still not changed.

This is a very basic code example

**Controller**

```
angular.module('instabugApp')
.controller('SdkIndexCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gradleOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: '14+' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Less than 14' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Less than 14 (Actionbar Sherlock)' }
  ];
  $scope.gradleChoice = $scope.gradleOptions[0];

  $scope.gradleChange = function() {
    console.log($scope.gradleChoice);
  };
  $scope.awesomeThings = [
    'HTML5 Boilerplate',
    'AngularJS',
    'Karma'
  ];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="columns large-6">
  {{gradleChoice.name}}
   <select ng-model="gradleChoice" ng-change="gradleChange()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in gradleOptions"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a working plunkr or fiddle ? Maybe here, the model is not yet updated at the time the change event triggers. That would allow rejecting the value change.

Comment: I don't get it, so what else should I listen for to bind to the model change?